# TWISTED server player position lag

Tags: python, inputstream, twisted, outputstream

Im currently making a multiplayer game, I'm sending over the users X position via InputStream and OutputStream... I'm getting lots of lag on the client side receiving. Heres the code:

First checking data:

```
def dataReceived(self, data):
    self.inBuffer = self.inBuffer + data
    while(True):
        if (len(self.inBuffer) < 4):
            return;

        msgLen = unpack('!I', self.inBuffer[:4])[0]
        # checks whether we do have a message.type which is 4bytes long, thats we are only checking the first 4 bytes then comparing it to see where the message is valid.
        if (len(self.inBuffer) < msgLen):
            return;

        messageString = self.inBuffer[4:msgLen+4]
        #emptys the buffer out
        self.inBuffer = self.inBuffer[msgLen+4:]
        message = MessageReader(messageString)
        self.processMessage(message)
        if PLAYERS_CONNECTED >= 2:
            self.startMatch(PLAYERIDS_CONNECTED)
```

checking message type:

```
def processMessage(self, message):
    messageId = message.readByte()
    if messageId == MESSAGE_PLAYER_CONNECTED:
        return self.playerConnected(message)
    if messageId == MESSAGE_START_MATCH:
        return self.startMatch(message)
    if messageId == MESSAGE_NOTIFY_READY:
        return self.notifyReady(message)
    if messageId == MESSAGE_MOVED_SELF:
        return self.movedSelf(message)
    if messageId == MESSAGE_YPOSITION:
```

processing message:

```
def movedSelf(self, message):
    posX = message.readInt()
    self.player.match.movedSelf(posX, self.player)
```

second part:

```
def movedSelf(self, posX, player):
    for i in range(0, len(self.players)):
        matchPlayer = self.players[i]
        if matchPlayer != player:
            if (matchPlayer.protocol):
                index = 0
                for i in PLAYERIDS_CONNECTED:
                    if(i == player.playerId):
                        matchPlayer.protocol.sendPlayerMoved(index, posX)
                    index = index + 1
                print("Player moved %s " % (index))
```

then sending the actual message:

```
def sendPlayerMoved(self, playerIndex, posX):
    message = MessageWriter()
    message.writeByte(MESSAGE_PLAYER_MOVED)
    message.writeInt(playerIndex)
    message.writeInt(posX)
    #self.log("Sent PLAYER_MOVED %d %d" % (playerIndex, posX))
    self.sendMessage(message)
```

the actualy messageconverter

```
class MessageWriter:

def __init__(self):
    self.data = ""

def writeByte(self, value):
    self.data = self.data + pack('!B', value)

def writeInt(self, value):
    self.data = self.data + pack('!I', value)

def writeString(self, value):
    self.writeInt(len(value))
    packStr = '!%ds' % (len(value))
    self.data = self.data + pack(packStr, value)
```

I honestly have no clue why there is lag, is it maybe cause the client sending the position is constantly sending the variables? what would be the best approach? I researched just to make sure that Twisted was asynchronous, which it is. To handle lets say 50 players.

Comment: didn't execute your code but I think the issue is the while loop in in `dataReceived()`. You shouldn't have blocking code like this in your Twisted code. See if you can remove the loop.

Comment: every iteration of the loop consumes some of inBuffer and the loop ends when inBuffer is short enough.  I'd say this is not exactly "blocking" code.  It's just input processing.

Comment: The question is vague.  What is "lots of lag"?  Be precise: how did you measure it, what results did you get, how did this differ from your goals?  And present a simple, self-contained, complete example: http://sscce.org/